# Could close the workbench without any hint about unsaved content?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP Application. I know the method **org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close()** could close the workbench and if the workbench has an open editor with unsaved content, the user will be given the opportunity to save it.

But whether I have the ability to close the workbench directly without saving any unsaved conent and without any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IWorkbenchConfigurer` which is passed to the WorkbenchAdvisor and WorkbenchWindowAdvisor has an `emergencyClose` which should do a close.

But note what the Javadoc for the method says:

> Forces the workbench to close due to an emergency. This method should
> only be called when the workbench is in dire straights and cannot
> continue, and cannot even risk a normal workbench close (think "out of
> memory" or "unable to create shell"). When this method is called, an
> abbreviated workbench shutdown sequence is performed (less critical
> steps may be skipped). The workbench advisor is still called; however,
> it must not attempt to communicate with the user.

Also note that the `Workbench` class is **internal** and should not be accessed directly - only with the `IWorkbench` interface.

Comment: Thank you, this's the right answer. But I'd also like to ask if it's possible to split the process into two parts. First using an api or other way to cancel all unsaved content, leaving the workbench in a state with no unsaved content, and then closing it.

Comment: I doubt it. Workbench has code to save everything, but I don't see anything to cancel everything - I don't think anything ever does that. You can always read the source to see what it does!